# Weird sideeffect printing some escape sequence to InelliJ-console, why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console, escaping

If I want to display the simple string "/\" on the IntelliJ-console by doing so:

```
System.out.println("/\\");
```

the console produces a hyperlink, which opens my Windows-Explorer if clicked on instead of the above expected output. I tried same code on IDE like Eclipse and NetBeans and it works like expected with no sideeffects. I asked other students working with IntelliJ, and they have the same results.

I solved the problem by appending a **non visible white space \u2060** like this:

```
System.out.println("/\\\u2060");
```

**Now my Question:**
Is this a special feature in IntelliJ or some other feature (like regular expression stuff) I don't understand yet?

Comment: It is IntelliJ or a plugin like [this](https://github.com/anthraxx/intellij-awesome-console)

Comment: thx for ur hint, after several tests with activating/deactivating plugins, I could identify the IntelliLang plugin. After deactivation u have to restart IDE (apply is not sufficient). Without this plugin however, you have no Android support anymore...

Comment: Leave it activated, then. It does not affect functionality.